# yii1 after converting string value to int value changed

Tags: php

```
(int) $string_id;
```

I am using the above command to change string value to int. But after converting the value, the value changed.

string value was : "86561198808311"
But after to integer: int(214748364)

Comment: Note that floats can be much larger even if you have int limitations. [**Demo**](https://eval.in/953354)

Answer (score 0):

From [php.net](http://php.net/) documentation about [Integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value
>   of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed).
>   64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except on
>   Windows prior to PHP 7, where it was always 32 bit

Very important for [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string):

> A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a
>   byte. This means that PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence
>   does not offer native Unicode support. See details of the string type.
>
> Note: As of PHP 7.0.0, there are no particular restrictions regarding the length of a string on 64-bit builds. On 32-bit builds and in earlier versions, a string can be as large as up to 2GB **(2147483647 bytes maximum)**

Finally, from [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function:

> The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum
>   signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on
>   such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The
>   maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is
>   9223372036854775807.